# Java Bounded type parameters error

Tags: java, generics

Why I cannot use Iterator here? 
Netbeans says that there is a difference between T in iterator and T in method declaration.

```
public abstract class DeviceManager<T> {


private List<T> devices = new ArrayList<T>();
private Class<T> deviceClass;

public DeviceManager(Class<T> deviceClass){
    this.deviceClass = deviceClass;
}

public  <T> T find(T device){
    Iterator<T> iterator = devices.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            T current = iterator.next();
            if (current.equals(device)) {
                return current;
            }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `<T>` from the method declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use generic method in your class, binding the type parameter into same name (T) as you are binding the type in your class declaration.

To implement your method correctly you should use type (class) generics. You should not define new generic types in the `find()` method, but re-use the ones that are already defined.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Test<T> {

    private List<T> devices = new ArrayList<T>();
    private Class<T> deviceClass;

    public Test(Class<T> deviceClass) {
        this.deviceClass = deviceClass;
    }

    public T find(T device) {
        Iterator<T> iterator = devices.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T current = iterator.next();
            if (current.equals(device)) {
                return current;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't *note* a lack of generics in the `find()` method. For example, it's return type is generic. :)

Comment: Yes meant that actually. Thanks for fixing as my thoughts didn't reach the keyboard :).

Answer (score 2):

You redeclare T as a generic type parameter in method find, hence it's a different type from the T in class DeviceManager.

Answer (score 2):

Your method declares a type as well, so this could be a different one than the one in the class. There's no need to declare the type in the method again.